# SCORM 1.2 API calls to set the grade in gradebook

Tags: scorm, desire2learn

What javascript API calls are needed to set the grade after completing an activity? Now I have these three calls:

```
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.min", 0);
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.max", 100);
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.raw", score);
```

I also set the status to completed:

```
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", "completed");
```

When I complete the activity as a student, sometimes I can see icon which tells that
activity is completed ("1 attempt(s)"), sometimes not. The gained score is never there.

Desire2Learn is at version 10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a SCORM expert by any means, but someone here that knows more about it than me makes these points:

- You also need to call `Commit` and `Terminate` and/or `LMSFinish`; you can find some good technical resources to [help developers at the SCORM website](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/), in case you don't already know about them.
- To verify scores and status getting to the Learning Environment, you can check the SCORM reports in the Web UI (Content > Table of Contents > View Report), which is the standard place to view SCORM results.
- If scores are set there, you can get them into the grade book in two ways:

  1. You can preview the content topic as an instructor: below the topic view, you'll find a spot to associate a grade item with the topic.
  2. If the DOME configuration variable `d2l.Tools.Content.AllowAutoSCORMGradeItem` is on for the course, that should automatically create a grade item for that SCORM content object.

Answer (score 0):

As Viktor says, you must invoked `LMSCommit` after using `LMSSetValue`, or else the data will not be persisted ('saved') in the LMS.

```
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.min", 0);
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.max", 100);
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.score.raw", score);
LMSSetValue("cmi.core.lesson_status", "completed");
LMSCommit(); //save in database
LMSFinish(); //exit course
```

Note that "`LMSSetValue`" is not an official SCORM call, it means you're working with a SCORM wrapper of some kind. Therefore where I say `LMSCommit` and `LMSFinish`, you might actually need to use different syntax -- I'm just guessing about the function names. Check your SCORM wrapper's documentation. The point is that you need to commit (save) and terminate (finish).

Comment: I had LMSCommit without LMSFinish. It worked on Moodle and Scorm Cloud, but not on D2L, now it is OK.

Comment: LMSFinish actually sets exit type internally, that might be the reason LMSFinish made the things. However LMS finish by default sets the value as 'logout' for exit type. Per SCORM spec 'suspend' is for resume(retain) and 'logout' is for fresh start. So it is good to set exit type explicitly with the value 'suspend' to cope with any LMS. 

Commit and Finish is enough. But setting exit type would add more sense to LMS(Especially for SCORM 2004 LMS) whether it should retain the values. 

`cmi.core.exit` - SCORM 1.2
`cmi.exit` - SCORM 2004